# How to disable scrolling simulation?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have implemented a scrollable container with a horizontal direction. The scrolling simulation is applied when I changed the content dimension of the scrollable container after reached it to the `maxScrollExtend` position. Please anyone let me know that how to restrict it while updating the scrolling content dimension. I need to restrict it for my use case.

Code snippet:

```
class NestedDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  NestedDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NestedDemoState createState() => _NestedDemoState();
}

class _NestedDemoState extends State<NestedDemo> {
  double width = 500;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
          height: 350,
          width: width,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          width = 250.0;
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to reach maxScrollExtend position on triggering an event. If you are trying to reach *maxScrollExtend* position on event. You can try the below snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:async';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: NestedDemo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NestedDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  NestedDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NestedDemoState createState() => _NestedDemoState();
}

class _NestedDemoState extends State<NestedDemo> {
  double width = 5000;
   ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(children: [
      
      SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
          height: 350,
          width: width,
        ),
      ),
         TextButton(child: Text('Please here'), onPressed:(){
         Timer(
                          Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          () => _scrollController.jumpTo(
                              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent));
      }),
        ]),
     
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          width = 250.0;
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to stop the scrolling physics: **NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()**

Comment: Hi Solomon, Thanks for your response. But, I don't need this actually. I want to disable the scrolling simulation when I changed the scroll content dimension at runtime. If you have run the sample, you would be noticed the simulation was applied to the scrollable container when I changed the size by button click after reached the maxScrollExtent position.  No need to go for the maxScrollExtent position programmatically. And also I tried the simulation is applied even though I set physics as 'NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`